# Amazon AWS - different access permissions for files in the same bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, file-permissions

Has anyone know is there an option to set file permissions for certain file on AWS S3 service to restrict access to that file only.

Here is the thing. I have a bucket with public read policy as below:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
    }
]}
```

There are bunch of files there which are related to some data in my database. When I delete that record it is not actually deleted. So I want to make that file (which is related to a deleted record) within this bucket to be public inaccessible.

I have two not very pretty ideas how to resolve this.

1. Copy all that data in another bucket with different policy.
2. Rename file and update policy to disable access to files with certain prefix of suffix (not sure if this is possible)

But all that requires write/delete action which I'd like to avoid. So the question is, is there is a way to set some kind of a permission to a single file to prevent an access?

Thanks,
Ante

Answer (score 0):

Check if AWS S3 ACL provides what you are looking for http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. All permissions are based on bucket polices that includes AWS users. What I need is a publicly accessible bucket in which certain files are inaccessible (like when you have 000 permissions on file in some standard 755 folder). Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I would suggest look for PreSignedURL [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)